# Random banner display using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, banner

I'm creating my website [located here](http://xclo.mobi/xclo2)

I'm trying to add a banner that changes every time a page refreshes. I have set up 2 examples in my database called "link 1" and "link 2". I will want to add more as and when I get them.

What I want to happen is this:

**I want to display one of the 2 images on my site and when the user refreshes the page, it will select one of the 2 images and this should continue every time the page refreshes.**

I'm testing this out in a page called banner.php before I move it to my footer.php and make it live.

I currently have this code In my banner.php page:

```
<?PHP
include_once('include/connection.php');

// Edit this number to however many links you want displaying
$num_displayed = 1 ;

// Select random rows from the database
    global $pdo;
      $query = $pdo->prepare ("SELECT * FROM banners ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $num_displayed"); 
      $query->execute();

// For all the rows that you selected
while ($row = execute($result)) 

{
// Display them to the screen...

echo "<a href=\"" . $row["link"] . "\">
<img src=\"" . $row["image"] . "\" border=0 alt=\"" . $row["text"] . "\">
</a>" ;
}
?>
<br /><br /><br />
```

But I am getting this error code:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function execute() in banner.php on line 13

My connection page is used by other pages so I know it works.

Please can some one help me on what I am doing wrong.

*Need any more info then please ask and I will add it to this post.*

Thank you.

Kev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
while ($row = execute($result))
```

with this:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch())
```

**EDIT**

This make it better to read.

```
while ($row = $query->fetch()) :
// Display them to the screen...
?>
<a href="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" border="0" alt="<?php echo $row['text'];?>">
</a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Comment: This gets rid of the error message but does not display the image

Comment: Oke use add `print_r($row);` in the while loop and see if you get a array of data, also check the path to the image. Do you see the a element on the screen?

Comment: This displays an _ at the top corner. Which refreshes when clicked.

Comment: See my edit to my answer, use that code to show your image this should be working! Also check your query with phpmyadmin or something else to be sure the query works.